# APFS container size is same after resize

Tags: macos, partition, high-sierra, apfs

After resizing the APFS container, it is not reflecting the changes but Disk Utility shows that the container is successfully resized.
Container size should be 128 GB but it's 78.09 GB. Strange!

[image]

[image]

```
Amans-iMac:~ aman$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1
Password:
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34       2014         
       2048     921600      1  GPT part - DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC
     923648     204800      2  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    1128448      32768      3  GPT part - E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE
    1161216       2048         
    1163264  236097536      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  237260800     962560      5  GPT part - DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC
  238223360  250173768      6  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  488397128          7         
  488397135         32         Sec GPT table
  488397167          1         Sec GPT header
Amans-iMac:~ aman$ 

Amans-iMac:~ aman$ diskutil list disk1
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk1
   1:           Windows Recovery                         471.9 MB   disk1s1
   2:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk1s2
   3:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows                 120.9 GB   disk1s4
   5:           Windows Recovery                         492.8 MB   disk1s5
   6:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         128.1 GB   disk1s6
Amans-iMac:~ aman$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange! After shrinking and resizing again **it's fixed now.**

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s6 128g

diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s6 0
```

[image]